# paypal activate IPN for expresscheckout

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am using Paypal's express Checkout for recurring payments

How can I activate an IPN URL for my recurring ExpressCheckout payment ? I found it can be set on the Paypal account's profile page, but what if I have 2 websites and I have set two IPN urls ?

Is there any way to set the IPN URl on the code (PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the NOTIFYURL* parameter in your SetExpressCheckout call. See the [NVP](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) or [SOAP](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_SOAP/) documentation as appropriate.